# HDF5 mounting files (with H5Fmount)

Tags: c++, mount, hdf5

I try to mount different files that all have the same structure to a single new one (in C++).
Therefore I create a new File "new.h5" and in there a new Group "/G".
The existing two files ("file1.h5" and "file2.h5") have some Attributes in the root-Group "/" and then a path "dataset1/data1/data", where "dataset1/data1" contains some Attributes and the "data"-Path with numerical Data in it.

```
 /dataset1
 /attribute1
 /attribute2
  /data1
   /data
   /attribute1
   /attribute2
```

In the new file I want a structure:

```
/G
 /dataset1
 /attribute1
 /attribute2
  /data1
   /data
   /attribute1
   /attribute2
 /dataset2
 /attribute1
 /attribute2
  /data1
   /data
   /attribute1
   /attribute2
```

I tried it this way:

```
#include "hdf5.h"
#ifdef OLD_HEADER_FILENAME
#include <iostream.h>
#else
#include <iostream>
#endif
#include <string>
#ifndef H5_NO_NAMESPACE
#ifndef H5_NO_STD
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#endif // H5_NO_STD
#endif
#include "H5Cpp.h"
#ifndef H5_NO_NAMESPACE
using namespace H5;
#endif

#define FILE_NAME_1 "file1.h5"
#define FILE_NAME_2 "file2.h5"
#define FILE_NAME_ALL "new.h5"

int main(void)
{

   hid_t fid1, fid2, fid3, gid;  /* Files and group identifiers */

   fid1 = H5Fopen(FILE_NAME_1, H5F_ACC_RDWR, H5P_DEFAULT);
   fid2 = H5Fopen(FILE_NAME_2, H5F_ACC_RDWR, H5P_DEFAULT);
   fid3 = H5Fcreate(FILE_NAME_ALL, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

   gid = H5Gcreate2(fid3, "/G", H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
   H5Gclose(gid);

   /*
    * Mount second file under G in the first file.
    */
   H5Fmount(fid3, "/G", fid1, H5P_DEFAULT);
   H5Fmount(fid3, "/G", fid2, H5P_DEFAULT);

   H5Fclose(fid1);
   H5Fclose(fid2);
   H5Fclose(fid3);

   return 0;
}
```

When I take a look to new.h5 with `h5dump` I get:

```
h5dump new.h5
HDF5 "new.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   GROUP "G" {
   }
}
}
```

so I created the Group G but there are no files in it?!
What went wrong?

And is there a possibility to rename the "dataset1" from the second file to "dataset2" while mounting the files or do I have to do it before?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I might have found a problem: I want to mount files from the root-group. What I mean: I want to have a common file that contains everything from the other two files. That makes it difficult to find a mounting point. It can't be the root-directory but there are no groups called "/G" in the existing files.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. Using `H5Fmount` only mounts the file at that location in memory. So when you close the files and exit your program the newfile (`new.h5`) does not (and will not) show the contents of the mounted files.

If you want this kind of behavior, use [`H5Lcreate_external`](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5L.html#Link-CreateExternal) to create external links.

I've changed your code to be C (not C++ - sorry, but the idea is the same):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <hdf5.h>

#define FILE_NAME_1 "file1.h5"
#define FILE_NAME_2 "file2.h5"
#define FILE_NAME_ALL "new.h5"

int main(void)
{

   hid_t fid1;  /* Files identifier */

   fid1 = H5Fcreate(FILE_NAME_ALL, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

   /*
    * Link "file1.h5" to group F1
    */
   H5Lcreate_external(FILE_NAME_1, "/", fid1, "/F1", H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

   /*
    * Link "file2.h5" to group F2
    */
   H5Lcreate_external(FILE_NAME_2, "/", fid1, "/F2", H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

   H5Fclose(fid1);

   return 0;
}
```

Where the contents of `file1.h5` and `file2.h5` are the same for the test case:

```
h5dump file1.h5
HDF5 "file1.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "D" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I32LE
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 4, 5 ) / ( 4, 5 ) }
      DATA {
      (0,0): 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
      (1,0): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
      (2,0): 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
      (3,0): 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
      }
   }
}
}
```

Then if we compile and run the test program:

```
h5cc -o test test.c && ./test
```

Finally dump the new file:

```
h5dump new.h5
HDF5 "new.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   EXTERNAL_LINK "F1" {
      TARGETFILE "file1.h5"
      TARGETPATH "/"
         GROUP "/" {
            DATASET "D" {
               DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I32LE
               DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 4, 5 ) / ( 4, 5 ) }
               DATA {
               (0,0): 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
               (1,0): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
               (2,0): 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
               (3,0): 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
               }
            }
         }
   }
   EXTERNAL_LINK "F2" {
      TARGETFILE "file2.h5"
      TARGETPATH "/"
         GROUP "/" {
            DATASET "D" {
               DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I32LE
               DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 4, 5 ) / ( 4, 5 ) }
               DATA {
               (0,0): 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
               (1,0): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
               (2,0): 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
               (3,0): 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
               }
            }
         }
   }
}
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! You said you used C not C++, this is a stupid question, sorry for this, but how do I know this? I tried to figure out the difference between HDF5 API (http://ftp.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/classH5_1_1AbstractDs.html) and the HDF5 C Library (Tutorial here: http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5Front.html) but I don't get it. When I use a .cpp file, can I mix those types?

Comment: @smaica Yes, you can mix the C++ and C api. The C++ objects are just thin wrappers around the C API and will provide a method to get their ID (e.g. H5::Group::getLocId) that can be passed to the C API. In many cases, there is no C++ class that provides the same functionality as the C API. I don't believe that the H5Lcreate_external C function has a C++ counterpart. Also, there is not nearly as much documentation for the C++ API as the C API.